# asp.net web api 2.2 self host slow processing of requests

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api2

Currently I have web api 2.2 self host server that started from console and more than 300  client's programs that sends requests through HttpClient each 30 seconds.
Server was configured for listening https connections like in post http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/enabling-https-with-self-hosted-asp-net-web-api/  
 
But from the recent times server stopped handle most part of clients requests. When  server was started he worked fine, but after several minutes he doesn't handle many of them. There is no exception on server but on client is TaskCanceledException (possible timeout of request). 
 
 
Then i tried to set options:
 
**HttpSelfHostConfiguration.MaxConcurrentRequests = 2000;** 
 
**ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 2000;** 
 
but it not help me.
 
 
After discovering a dump file of process i found that there was 7 threads that stuck in method "HttpReceiveClientCertificate" [stack trace image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zIxp.png). For testing i removed HttpSelfHostConfiguration.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate and requests are normally received to the server.
It seems that not all requests handled because finding certificate take a lot of time.
 
**How can i increase handling incoming requests?**

Comment: Host the app on IIS perhaps? I wouldn't use self-host or IIS Express in a production environment.

Comment: Also, did you check the memory usage of your application, maybe you're having a memory leak?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit
No. It is console appliacation that start asp.net web api 2.2 self host server like in post http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api. We have another highload selfhost server, but without using https connection, it works fine.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit  Memory is enough, the process takes 400MB memory. Private bytes takes only 50-100MB and other 300MB is "working set"

Comment: Have you tested this under high load?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit No, i didn't tested it

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

In my case SSL certificate configuration was done using 'netsh http add sslcert' command.

Adding 'clientcertnegotiation=Enable' allowed to increase number of handled requests.